# why http is not working on 80 port for lightpd?

Tags: http, yocto, lighttpd, webui

I am facing an issue with lighttpd 1.4.69 version with yocto dunfell.
We are getting the port 80 in listen mode and PID is lighttpd only.

`tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1325/lighttpd`

When i try to search the IP of device it's not loading any HTML page.
Any idea why such thing is happening?

I am expecting the communication should happened over HTTP protocall using lighttpd, so i can open HTML pages which are availale in the device/board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the http port in the lighttpd.conf file, and run the lighttpd service.

Steps:

```
    server.port = 8080

    pkill -9 lighttpd
    
    lighttpd -m /usr/lib -f /etc/lighttpd.conf
```